# Facebook api open graph publish action syntax error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I am a little lost.

I just created an action in facebook and I am trying to publish it in my app.

facebook gave me this code:

```
curl -F 'access_token=xxx' \
     -F 'gag=http://samples.ogp.me/436800766355204' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/xxx:laugh_at'
```

When I put that in my php script I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: this is not PHP code. It's a shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not PHP-code. It's meant to be pasted into a command line.
I recommend using the [PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/), but I suppose you could do it like this:

```
<?php
    exec("curl -F 'access_token=xxx' -F 'gag=http://samples.ogp.me/436800766355204' 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/xxx:laugh_at'");
?>
```